# ng-repeat in linked data object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `Node` object inside my Angular controller. Each `Node` has a `next` property which points to the next item:

```
$scope.Stack = function () {
        this.top = null;
        this.rear = null;
        this.size = 0;
        this.max_size = 15;
    };


    $scope.Node = function (data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
        this.previous = null;
    };

    $scope.Stack.prototype.pushUp = function (data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
            if (data.items[i]) {

                var node = new $scope.Node(data.items[i]);
                if (node) {
                    node.previous = this.top;

                    if (this.top) {
                        this.top.next = node;
                    }

                    this.top = node;

                    // if first push, the set the rear
                    if (this.size == 0) {
                        this.rear = node;
                    }

                    this.size += 1;
                }
            }
        }

    };
```

Creating object:

```
$scope.Timeline = new $scope.Stack();
```

My question: is there a way to iterate over linked data structures like this using ng-repeat/Angular?

Comment: ng-repeat can only iterate over official JavaScript Collections (i.e. arrays and key value pairs).

Answer (score 1):

According to the AngularJS docs,

> variable in expression – where variable is the user defined loop variable and expression is a scope expression giving the collection to enumerate.

therefore ngRepeat can only be used to iterate over a Javascript "Collection". Collections include Arrays, Maps, Sets, and WeakMaps. So the answer to your question is No, you cannot iterate over a linked structure.